# Wraparound in unsigned arithmetic operation

Tags: c, misra

The following MISRA violations appeared while analyzing the following code:

```
#define z  (USHORT)14745

#define Convert(x) ((((USHORT)x*(unsigned short)1000) + ((z) / (USHORT)2)) /(z))

static const USHORT array [2] = 

{
   Convert(176), -> Line "1"
   Convert(206)  -> Line "2"
};
```

The following MISRA violations are detected on both lines "1", "2":

- Integral promotion : unsigned short promoted to unsigned int.
  REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.2.1.1 Characters and Integers
- Constant: Wraparound in unsigned arithmetic operation.
  MISRA-C:2004 Rule 12.11; REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.1.2.5 Types
- The result of this cast is implicitly converted to another type.

My question is: Why there will be a wraparound in this operation ?!

Note: When I am checking the values of `array` with debugger:

```
array [2] = 
{
  12,
  14
}
```

which are the correct values.

Comment: Because `176000` and `206000` both exceed the value that `USHORT` can hold.

Comment: What's the messy "convert" line supposed to be? Part of a macro? It is not valid C, from what I can tell.

Comment: @Vane, but the result at the end is correct, Why ?!

Comment: @Lundin, check the last edit

Comment: Rule 12.11 is advisory. Let's say you were "lucky" with the conversion, and the rules are there to prevent you being "unlucky"..

Comment: Actually there is no unsigned wrap-around in the actual expression, because the operands have been implicitly promoted to `int`. It is good that the tool gave a warning still, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to Integral Promotion:

> Integer types smaller than int are promoted when an operation is
>   performed on them. If all values of the original type can be
>   represented as an int, the value of the smaller type is converted to
>   an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.

So that, the macro `Convert(206) [((((unsigned short)206*(unsigned short)1000) + ((z) / (USHORT)2)) /(z))]` will be executed as following:

1. "206" will be promoted to signed int.
2. "1000" will be promoted to signed int.
3. The operation "206 * 1000" will be performed and the result will be of type signed int also -> "206000".
4. z, 2 will be promoted to signed int.
5. The operation z / 2 will be performed and the result will be of type signed int -> "14745 / 2" = "7372"
   6."206000" + "7372" will be performed and the result will be of type signed int -> 213372
6. "213372" will be divided by "14745" resulting "14"

Comment: Technically the integer constants are already of type `int`. Though you casted some of them to USHORT and those will get promoted back to `int`. Meaning that all casts in this snippet are completely superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 176 * 1000 will not fit inside a 16 bit unsigned short. So by using MISRA, you prevented severe bugs in your code, because the algorithm was calculated on signed `int` type and the result of it implicitly showed back into an unsigned short. If you get the expected results, it is entirely by coincidence/luck.

Note that there are two other advisory MISRA violations that weren't reported:

- function-like macros are not allowed (rule 19.7)
- you should use a pre-defined set of integer typedefs like `stint.h` (rule 6.3)

Both of these are very good rules and not something you should ignore. (Also it should have warned about you using literals without 'u' suffix.)

The fix is to replace the messy macro with a type safe function, that contains no implicit promotions (given 32 bit `int`):

```
uint16_t convert (uint16_t x)
{
  const uint16_t z = 14745u;
  uint32_t result32;

  result32 = (uint32_t)x * 1000ul + (uint32_t)z / 2ul / (uint32_t)z
  return (uint16_t)result32;
}
```

Comment: "because the algorithm was calculated on signed int " Do you mean UNsigned int instead ?

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy No, all small integer types such as `unsigned short` get implicitly promoted to (signed) `int` whenever used in an expression. This is subtle and dangerous, and why MISRA is full of very sound rules to prevent such bugs. One of the main missions of MISRA actually seems to be teaching programmers about the dangers of implicit promotions. There is a frightening amount of veteran C programmers who don't know about the various implicit type promotion rules in C. I will admit I didn't have a clue myself, before reading MISRA in 2004.